# GetUserAsync returns null in discord.NET with SERVER MEMBERS INTENT enabled

Tags: c#, discord.net

`var user = await guild.GetUserAsync("user id here", CacheMode.AllowDownload);`

The `guild` is valid but the `user` is null whenever the user id isn't the bot's one, what should I do?

I saw similar questions but the answers were all talking about enabling **Server Members Intent**, but I've already enabled it [Server Members Intent enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8ojO.png)

Comment: you also need to specify the intents you want in the DiscordSocketConfig

Comment: @Anu6is thank you, now it is working properly!